# Mysql holds SELECT Statment while INSERT INTO or UPDATE query are in progress

Tags: mysql, select, insert, locking, sql-update

I need to know if there is any technique in mysql from which we can put on hold the SELECT statement while INSERT INTO or UPDATE queries are running on the same table.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Finally we have people asking how to do this, not how to get rid of this

Comment: Yes because I need this in one of my module.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve by locking the whole table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue this:

```
LOCK TABLES mytable
```

prior to the `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

When you're done, run

```
UNLOCK TABLES
```

However, table-based locks are rarely the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Lock Table` see this documnetation file http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html